# c++ ternary operator expected an expressionC/C++(29)

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, ternary

[image: 1]

```
double recursively(int n) {
    (n==0)?(return 0.0):((n==1)?(return 1.0):(return 2*recursively(n-1)+recursively(n-2)));
}
```

When I use the ternary operator in a recursive function it is not showing "expected an expressionC/C++(29)" error. I am using Visual Studio Code. Any possible reason?

Comment: Please add the code as text, and not images.

Comment: Control flow keywords, such as `return` should not be used within  expressions. It should be written in front of it.

Comment: "... it is not showing "expected an expressionC/C++(29)" error" when it is *not* showing an error, then whats the problem? is this a typo?

Comment: `return (n==0)?(0.0):(1.42);`

Comment: `return 0.0`,  `return 1.0`, etc are statements, not expressions.   As the error message says, the ternary operator expects expressions  i.e. in `a ? b : c` it is necessary that `a`, `b,` and `c` all be valid expressions.    That is also true when the expressions also use the ternary operator.      The simple way is to move the `return` keyword outside, and remove all the other places where it is used  i.e.  `return (n == 0) ? (0.0) : ((n == 1) ? 1.0 :`  <etc>

Comment: Try to avoid the ternary operator just to type lesss. The major usecase for the ternary operator is to initialize a variable directly. In your case you should use ```if```.

Answer (score 1):

The official name is "the conditional operator", and it is an expression that produces a value - `a ? b : c` is not shorthand for `if (a) b; else c;` but a choice between the values `b` and `c`.

Rewrite to return the value of the expression:

```
return n==0 ? 0.0 : (n==1 ? 1.0 : 2*recursively(n-1)+recursively(n-2));
```

The parentheses around `n == 1 ? ...` are technically redundant, but make it easier to read.
I sometimes break long lines like this:

```
return n == 0 
       ? 0.0 
       : n == 1 
         ? 1.0 
         : 2 * recursively(n-1) + recursively(n-2);
```